# Change clear SQL to queryBuilder subquery

Tags: mysql, query-builder

Order entity has OneToMany OrderStatsu so any order have many statuses and I want to find all orders where last status = x.

My query look like this (and work)

```
SELECT o.id, os.status_id FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT *
        FROM order_status
    GROUP BY orders_id DESC
    ) AS os
ON o.id = os.orders_id
```

But I want to get it as object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `GROUP BY orders_id DESC` is a wrong syntax. You can change your query like

```
SELECT o.id, os.status_id 
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN(SELECT status_id, orders_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(statuses ORDER BY statuses DESC) AS Status
FROM order_status
GROUP BY orders_id) os
ON o.id = os.orders_id
WHERE LEFT(os.Status) = 'X';
```